# Is there a workaround for WAT080 : Failed to locate the Microsoft Azure SDK

Tags: .net, visual-studio, azure, msbuild, azure-sdk

I'm building a project that requires the Azure SDK to be installed.  Unfortunately, I'm unable to install the SDK because the VSTools installer does not run within a Docker container.  I'm trying to *recreate* the steps the installer does so the project thinks the SDK is correctly installed.  The error message I get is:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Windows
>   Azure Tools\2.9\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets(1093,5): error : WAT080
>   : Failed to locate the Microsoft Azure SDK. Please make sure t he
>   Microsoft Azure SDK v2.9 is installed.
>   [C:\BuildAgent\work\da35ef67e7dea9a9\EMCloudService\EMCloudService.ccproj]

Line 1093 in the `.targets` file is:

```
  <Target
      Name="VerifySDKInstallation"> // <---- Line 1093

    <WATMessage Condition=" !Exists('$(ServiceHostingSDKInstallDir)') or
                            !Exists('$(ServiceHostingSDKBinDir)') or
                            !Exists('$(ServiceHostingSDKTaskPath)') "
                Type="Error"
                Code="WAT080"
                Arguments="$(ActiveAzureSdkVersion)" />

    <WATMessage Condition=" !Exists('$(AzureClientLibInstallDir)') or
                            !Exists('$(AzureClientLibToolsRefDir)') or
                            !Exists('$(StorageClientAssemblyFullPath)') "
                Type="Error"
                Code="WAT081"
                Arguments="$(ActiveAzureClientLibVersion)" />

  </Target>
```

So, it seems the error is because one of those three paths do not exist.  The first one comes from the following line:

```
<ServiceHostingSDKInstallDir Condition=" '$(ServiceHostingSDKInstallDir)' == '' ">$([MSBuild]::GetRegistryValueFromView('$(ServiceHostingSDKRegistryKey)', 'InstallPath', null, RegistryView.Registry32))</ServiceHostingSDKInstallDir>
```

So, basically it's looking in the registry.  I copied this value from a working machine, and it has the value "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure.NET SDK\"

I copied that directory over.  The next is ServiceHostingSDKBinDir, which is defined as:

```
<ServiceHostingSDKBinDir     Condition=" '$(ServiceHostingSDKBinDir)' == '' ">$(ServiceHostingSDKInstallDir)bin\</ServiceHostingSDKBinDir>
```

So that should be fine since ServiceHostingSDKInstallDir exists.  Lastly is ServiceHostingSDKTaskPath, which is:

```
<ServiceHostingSDKTaskPath   Condition=" '$(ServiceHostingSDKTaskPath)' == '' ">$(ServiceHostingSDKBinDir)Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.MSBuildTasks.dll</ServiceHostingSDKTaskPath>
```

So, it really seems like I should just be able to copy over the "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure.NET SDK\" directory, pass in the correct parameters for ActiveAzureSdkVersion and ServiceHostingSDKInstallDir, and everything should work:

```
msbuild EM.sln `
  /p:ActiveAzureSdkVersion="2.9" `
  /p:ServiceHostingSDKInstallDir="C:/Program Files/Microsoft SDKs/Azure/.NET SDK/"
```

Yet, I still get the same error.  Can anyone think of anything else I'd need to copy over or pass in?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this one out.  What *really* helped is adding the following to the `.targets` file, just below line 1093:

```
<Message Text="ServiceHostingSDKInstallDir = $(ServiceHostingSDKInstallDir)" />
<Message Text="ServiceHostingSDKBinDir = $(ServiceHostingSDKBinDir)" />
<Message Text="ServiceHostingSDKTaskPath = $(ServiceHostingSDKTaskPath)" />
```

This let me see what paths it was trying to look for.  In the build output, I then got:

```
ServiceHostingSDKInstallDir = C:/Program Files/Microsoft SDKs/Azure/.NET SDK/
ServiceHostingSDKBinDir = C:/Program Files/Microsoft SDKs/Azure/.NET SDK/bin\
ServiceHostingSDKTaskPath = C:/Program Files/Microsoft SDKs/Azure/.NET SDK/bin\Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.MSBuildTasks.dll
```

So, the path `C:/Program Files/Microsoft SDKs/Azure/.NET SDK/bin\` does not exist because it's missing the version number.  It turns out that `ActiveAzureSdkVersion` parameter is only used when the path is obtained through the registry, so passing it in is meaningless in my case.  Instead, I need to pass in the full path to the SDK, including the version:

> MSBuild.exe .\EM.sln /p:ServiceHostingSDKInstallDir="C:/Program
>   Files/Microsoft SDKs/Azure/.NET SDK/v2.9/"

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Glad to know you have resolved this issue, and thanks for sharing your solution here :).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a workaround for WAT080 : Failed to locate the Microsoft Azure SDK

According to the file `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets(1093,5)`, we could get following code snippet:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ActiveAzureSdkVersion Condition=" '$(ActiveAzureSdkVersion)' == '' ">$([MSBuild]::GetRegistryValueFromView('HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio\15.0\v2.9', 'ActiveWindowsAzureVersion', null, RegistryView.Registry32))</ActiveAzureSdkVersion>
    <!-- Sdk reversion -->
    <ActiveAzureSdkVersion Condition=" '$(ActiveAzureSdkVersion)' == '' ">2.9</ActiveAzureSdkVersion>
    <ServiceHostingSDKRegistryKey>HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\ServiceHosting\v$(ActiveAzureSdkVersion)</ServiceHostingSDKRegistryKey>
    <ServiceHostingSDKInstallDir Condition=" '$(ServiceHostingSDKInstallDir)' == '' ">$([MSBuild]::GetRegistryValueFromView('$(ServiceHostingSDKRegistryKey)', 'InstallPath', null, RegistryView.Registry32))</ServiceHostingSDKInstallDir>

    <!-- Ensure ServiceHostingSDKInstallDir has a trailing slash, so it can be concatenated -->
    <ServiceHostingSDKInstallDir Condition=" '$(ServiceHostingSDKInstallDir)' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('$(ServiceHostingSDKInstallDir)')">$(ServiceHostingSDKInstallDir)\</ServiceHostingSDKInstallDir>

    ...
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>
```

We could to know the value of the parameter `ServiceHostingSDKRegistryKey` is:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\ServiceHosting\v$(ActiveAzureSdkVersion)
```

Simple to know the value of `$(ActiveAzureSdkVersion)` is **2.9**, so **the value of `ServiceHostingSDKInstallDir` should be value of the `InstallPath` of the parameter `ServiceHostingSDKRegistryKey`**.

**Then**, we open the regedit and switch path to the above registry key:

[image]

The value of the `InstallPath` is `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\.NET SDK\v2.9\` rather than the old value `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure.NET SDK\`.

Besides, you can find the location of that Azure SDK is also `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\.NET SDK\v2.9`, you specified it in your command line with parameter `/p:ServiceHostingSDKInstallDir`.

So, the reason for this issue is that the value of registry key is not correct. Although you re-write it with `/p:ServiceHostingSDKInstallDir`, when import the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets` to the project file and execute the target `VerifySDKInstallation`, it seems MSBuild/Visual Studio will invoke the parameter $(ServiceHostingSDKInstallDir) in the `.targets` file based on the principle of proximity.

The workaround for this issue, you can try to change the registry key to the correct path or if you do not want to modify the registry, you can try to copy the SDK folder to the old path `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure.NET SDK\`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'll give this a shot, but I'm hoping to find a solution that doesn't require modifying the registry in any way and only relies on copying files to the right places and passing in the right MSBuild parameters.

Comment: @MikeChristensen, If you do not want to modify the registry, you can try to copy the SDK folder to the old path `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure.NET SDK\`.

Comment: I copied `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\.NET SDK\v2.9` to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure.NET SDK\v2.9` but I still get the same error.  I tried running `msbuild .\EM.sln /p:ActiveAzureSdkVersion="2.9" /p:ServiceHostingSDKInstallDir="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure.NET SDK"` (which is the _new_ folder)

Comment: I also tried copying `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\ServiceHosting` over from a working machine and ran MSBuild normally (with no parameters) and I get the same error.  There must be something else the installer is doing.

Comment: Figured this one out (See answer below).  Thanks for your help!  BTW, I don't suppose you know anyone who could take a look at [this bug](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/issues/1499) which is the reason I have to jump through all these hoops in the first place.